# sagepay form protocol 3 encryption e new form error

Tags: forms, encryption, opayo

We are unable to make the form for protocol 3 work correctly and getting a "5068 encryption method is not supported by this protocol version" message. The code we have for the encryption is shown below. Can anyone tell me where we are going wrong?

```
$stuff = @pkcs5_pad($stuff, 16);

$crypt = @base64_encode(@mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $order['gateway']['transkey'], $stuff, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '1234567812345678'));

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) {
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a simulator account for that request? If so, the version 3 protocol does not yet work with the simulator account, nor do Sage Pay have an estimate on when it will be available.

You will need to use a test account to test a full v3 integration, otherwise you can integrate to v2.23, commenting out the additional v3 fields, and test with the simulator account.
Then later on adding in the v3 additional fields and testing via the simulator when it's available or on a test account.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption password will differ on your Test and Live account. If you require your encryption password please call our Support line on 0845 111 4455 who will be able to send it to a registered contact on the Sage Pay account.

If you are using Simulator - it is not available on v3.00. The above comment is correct, you may use v2.23 to test your integration. If ok, change to v3.00 ensuring your are checking all mandatory fields are being used and the return responses are ok.

V3.00 Form Protocol and Integration Guideline is available [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1151/download-document/FORMProtocolandIntegrationGuidelinesV3%200.pdf?token=ooTED17UxDNLPw0abQdGUQam_24LVFwEz0_096FHKtY). The Crypt field should contain all the other transaction information in plain text as Name=Value fields separated by ‘&’ characters. This string should then be encrypted using the AES/CBC/PCKS#5 algorithm and the pre-registered Encryption password, then subsequently Base64 encoded to allow safe transport in an HTML form. The crypt must be 16 characters.

If you need further support, you may email feedback@sagepay.com and reference this forum post URL.

Sage Pay Support